# MVC3 ajaxgrid scaffolding error, Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I'm using MVC3 ajaxgrid scaffolding with EF4.1 code first and i've this error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery'

The code with the error in, is autogenerated:

```
public ActionResult GridData(int start = 0, int itemsPerPage = 20, string orderBy = "UserID", bool desc = false)
        {
            Response.AppendHeader("X-Total-Row-Count", repository.Users.Count().ToString());
            ObjectQuery<User> users = (repository as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<User>();

            users = repository.Users.Include(u => u.Role); //ERROR HERE

            users = users.OrderBy("it." + orderBy + (desc ? " desc" : ""));    
            return PartialView(users.Skip(start).Take(itemsPerPage));
        }
```

This is the Users repository method and the Roles Foreign Key

```
  public IQueryable<Entities.User> Users
        {
            get { return context.Users; }
        }


  public IQueryable<Entities.Role>Roles
        {
            get { return context.Roles; }
        }
```

How can i resolve the conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the Lambda and use the related object:

```
var users = repository.Users.Include("Role");  //ERROR HERE
```

Assuming the entity User has a navigational property Role.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is clear:

You have `users` variable with `ObjectQuery<User>` type then you assign that variable result of a query which is `IQueryable<User>`.

**UPDATE:**
Try the code below:

```
public ActionResult GridData(int start = 0, int itemsPerPage = 20, string orderBy = "UserID", bool desc = false)
{
   Response.AppendHeader("X-Total-Row-Count", repository.Users.Count().ToString());
   //ObjectQuery<User> users = (repository as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<User>();

   var users = repository.Users.Include(u => u.Role); //ERROR HERE

   users = users.OrderBy("it." + orderBy + (desc ? " desc" : ""));    
   return PartialView(users.Skip(start).Take(itemsPerPage));
}
```

Comment: This statement is automatically made by the scaffolding, i do not know why it use a ObjectQuery<User> Is there a way to cast or modify the users variable to made it work? if i cannot cast, how can i modify the code? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately i've this error on the last but one line

The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Queryable.OrderBy<TSource,TKey>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,TKey>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Comment: So comment that line also, cause the string can not passed as Expression to OrderBy, and I thought there may be an Extension Method that accept string